# unchangeable leading characters in HTML input?

Tags: javascript, html, input, parsley

How do I generate an input element that has a default starting value in there that is unchangeable?  For example, I am looking for a number from the user but I want '333' to be already in the input text box since all inputs will start with that number.  I also don't want the user to be able to change it.  I need the 333 to be part of the value also rather than just being added via style since I need to do validation on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use 2 inputs as William B suggested but I'd consider whether to use the `disabled` attribute or the `readonly` attribute.  The `disabled` attribute won't allow the first input to be focused and the default browser styling will give it a gray background.  The `readonly` attribute will allow it to be focused and may have a more desirable initial styling.

Comment: good point - i've updated my answer to use a `readonly` input instead of disabled.

Answer (score 1):

One possibilty using JavaScript:

```js
nine = document.getElementById("nine");
nine.addEventListener("keydown", function (ev) {
  var el = this;
  var value = el.value;
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (el.value.indexOf("333") != 0) {
      el.value = value;
    } 
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="333" id="nine" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using 2 inputs that look like a single input, with the first one readonly. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/39whrqup/2/

```
<input readonly value="333" class="static-input">
<input class="nonstatic-input">

.static-input {
  margin-right: -20px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 0;
}

.nonstatic-input {
  border: 0;
}
```

When reading the user input you will have to prepend the static portion, naturally:

```
var userInput = document.querySelector('input.static-input').value +
                document.querySelector('input.nonstatic-input').value;
```