# Keep input's place holder text while typing

Tags: javascript, html

I have this input :

```
  <input type="number" class="textfield numberField font"  name="Price" placeholder="Price"><br>
```

So the text `place holder` is **price**.
When user start typing I would like to keep the word `price`.

So if he types *65* he will see on the input :

```
Price 65
```

Do I need to create another div inside for the word `price`, or can it be done using js or html ?

Comment: Are you ok with using some javascript?

Comment: I'd put "price" in a label, and keep the input's value numeric, this will make validation and using the input in your business logic easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to be like that.

```css
  
.full-input {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='full-input'><label for='price'>Price</label>
  <input type='number'class="textfield numberField font"  name="Price">
 </div>
```

Comment: You need to make the `input` have an `id` of "price" and not just a `name` for the `label` to work.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to check if the `value` is equal to an empty string, and if so, manually set the `value` to `Price`. Note that this will require removing the `type="number"` restriction.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onkeydown = function() {
  if (this.value == '') {
    this.value = "Price ";
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="textfield numberField font" name="Price" placeholder="Price">
```

If you only want to allow numbers, then you could add a `pattern` validation of something like `pattern="Price [0-9]"`:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onkeydown = function() {
  if (this.value == '') {
    this.value = "Price ";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="textfield numberField font" name="Price" placeholder="Price" pattern="Price [0-9]">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Keep in mind that both approaches would have the word `Price` in the `value` (which may be unintended). Creating a `<label>` may be more appropriate for your situation.

Comment: This would still have the word inside the value, which placeholder doesn't do.

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely a downside. But you can't have the word "Price" 'inside' the `<input>` without having it as the `value`... unless you were to strip the word on form submission, or simply use a `<label>` and some CSS.

Comment: @ObsidianAge It works for the most part, except you can delete the Price. Try writing code to disallow that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218331/unchangeable-leading-characters-in-html-input this link could help your write that

Comment: Thanks so it looks like the best thing to do is another label to the left of the input? like: priceLabel | input

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```css
.textfield.labeled>.label {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.textfield.labeled .label:first-child+input {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}

.textfield.labeled>input {
    padding-left: 3px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(34,36,38,.15);
    box-shadow: none;
}

.textfield.labeled {
    display: inline-flex;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
}

.label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="textfield labeled">
  <div class="label">
    Price
  </div>
  <input type="number" class="textfield numberField font"  name="Price" placeholder="Price">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice styling, but you get benefits from using the semantic tag `label`--namely, when you connect the `for` attribute with the `input`'s `id` attribute (same string), a label click will put users into the field itself.